# mongoose string.slice before query $regex

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a video model like,

```
video{
  videoName: {type: String, required: true}
  //other schema.....
}
```

and store a lot of filenames in database video1.mp4, video2.mp4, video3.mp4.........

But, I face a problem when I want to query videos,

```
 Video.find('videoName': { $regex: keyword, $options: 'i'}, function (err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    res.json(docs);
});
```

if my keyword = m, p or 4, all videos will be displayed. So my idea is changing the filename before $regex query like videoName.slice.

Is it possible or just can change my schema and add new value without filename extension?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible in a single query with aggregation using [**$substr**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/)

```
db.video.aggregate([
   {
      $project:{
         videoName:1,
         subName:{
            $substr:[
               "$videoName",
               0,
               {
                  $subtract:[
                     {
                        $strLenCP:"$videoName"
                     },
                     4
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $match:{
         subName:{
            $regex:/dom/gi
         }
      }
   }
])
```

output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c8d9980750c5848e55b265"), "videoName" : "random.mp4", "subName" : "random" }
```

However, depending on your collection size, it's likely to be slow (**`$project`** stage on entire collection can be very expensive), so it may be better to store name without extension along with the full name in each document!